# Can we define the distance from $x$ to boundary $A$ when $A$ is open? (Michael Spivak "Calculus on Manifolds" on p.64)

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces

I am reading "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak.
On p.64 in this book, Spivak wrote "distance from $x$ to boundary $A$" when $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open.
Intuitively, I think we can define the distance from $x$ to boundary $A$ when $A$ is open.
But I cannot prove that.

Please answer the following question:

Let $X$ be a metric space.
Let $A \subset X$.
Let $x$ be an element of $X$.
Let $D := \{r\in \mathbb{R} ; r = \text{d}(a, x) \text{ for some }a \in A\}$.

If $A$ is compact, then there exists the minimum value of $D$.
Even if $A$ is closed but not compact, I guess there exists the minimum value of $D$.

Comment: For one thing, the boundary of $A$ is the same as the boundary of the complement of $A$; if one is open the other is closed, in case you think "open" or "closed" has something to do with it. In any case, the **boundary** of any set is a closed set, for what it's worth. Actually, the only thing you have to worry about is that the boundary of $A$ might be empty. If the whole space is connected, that can only happen if $A$ is the empty set or the whole space.

Comment: @bof Thank you very much for your very nice comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distance from a point to **any subset** of a metric space is always defined. It is an infimum, not necessarily a minimum.

A well known example where $D$ doesn't have a minimum is the following: Consider $C[0,1]$ with the sup norm. Let $A=\{f: \int_0^{1/2} f(x)dx-\int_{1/2}^{1} f(x)dx=1\}$. Then we can show that the infimum of $D$ corresponding to $x=0$  is $1$ but if this is attained we will get the contradiction  that there is a continuous function $f$ which has the value $1$ for $x <\frac 1 2$ and the value $-1$ for $x >\frac 1  2$. I will add details if necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much again, Kavi Rama Murthy.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with $\inf \{d(x,a) : a \in \partial A\}$?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Charles Hudgins.

Answer (score 0):

After I posted the above question, maybe I solved the problem.
Am I correct or not?

Let $r \in D$.
Then $A' := \{y \in X ; \text{d}(x, y) \leq r\} \cap A$ is compact.

Then we can define the distance between $x$ and $A$ as the distance between $x$ and $A'$.

Comment: Distance is defined as in infimum . No need for the infimum to be attained.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you very much!